# Can an element with no pre-image be the pre-image of some element?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

This might be something absolutely elementary, ridiculous or obvious (or way too complex) but the thing is, I have no clue and have found no information about it. 
Let's say we have some set resulting from a mapping, and that set contains some element *e* which has no pre-image in the domain of the function, now we compose this function with one another such that this set defines itself a domain. How can this element *e* be the pre-image of some element in the new codomain if it has no inverse operator? Isn't it that we do not have enough information about it as to act upon it? I somehow get the idea that in mathematics the behaviour of things is far more important than their *presence*.

Plus, can somebody recommend me some book or source which will explain elementary stuff like this such that people which really are looking for just elementary stuff will understand it?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. You ask us to consider "some set resulting from a mapping, and that set contains some element e which has no pre-image", but how could $e$ be in such a set if it has no pre-image? Could you perhaps give a simple example?

Comment: Oh it might be that 'resulting' is not the right expression, I rather meant.. a function which maps some elements onto another set so that there are elements in that set which have no pre-image (can't be obtained with the function?). It is absolutely possible that I am confusing many concepts and have misunderstood injective functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking then consider two functions:

$f: A \rightarrow B, f(x)=x^2$ where $A = B = \mathbb{R}$

$g: X\rightarrow Y, g(x)=x^2$ where $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (real numbers $\geq 0$).

Note that $-1 \in A$ and $-1 \in  B$, but certainly there is no real number $r$ such that $r^2=-1$. As such, we say that $f$ is not onto. However, note that we still have $f(-1) = 1$, so $-1$ is an element with no pre-image but is itself the preimage of something.

Now, consider $g$ and note that $\forall y \in Y$, there is some $x\in X$ such that $g(x)=y$, namely $x=\pm\sqrt{y}$. Since $g$ can map to any element of $Y$ (the co-domain), we call $g$ an "onto" or "surjective" map. Notice that simply by changing our codomain the mapping $x\mapsto x^2$ can be surjective. As such, it's often very important to specify domains and codomains along with mappings when talking about functions.

Hopefully this cleared some things up!

Comment: It did thanks! I completely forgot that we are free to _restrict_ our codomain!